# Outlines package indent of first dot

Tags: packages, lists, indentation

I would like to see the dots of the list in an `outline` environment to be aligned with the first word. But I don't find much help regarding this package: [Outlines](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/outlines/outlines.pdf).

How can I indent the full list?

```
 \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{outlines}
   \begin{document}
    \section{title}
     \begin{outline}
          \1 Online frei verfügbar für alle
          \1 Einfach in der Bedienung
          \2 Auf mobilen Geräten automatisch laufen. - ohne Zwischenschritte.
          \2 Den Benutzer unterstützen in der Suche der beschriebenen Objekten.
          \1 Offlinefähig - Keine Datenabhängigkeit während der Tour.
     \end{outline}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Unless you're using `lualatex` or `xelatex`, you will get into troubles with the umlauts without using the `inputenc` package with `utf8` encoding, for example

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "first word" when you look at [this output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoMzB.png)?

Comment: @Werner - hmm. there should be a section title and i would like to get the dot beneth where the titles first letter starts.

Comment: @novski: Sure. Are you stuck on using [`outlines`](//ctan.org/pkg/outlines), or can you switch to (say) [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) (or something else)?

Comment: that wold mean to rewrite quite a lot. ~ >80 pages document with a lot such lists...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer im using utf8 and inputenc in my main doc. this MWE may got a bit too short...

Comment: if i do that, how is the command to set the itemindent? this does not work: \setlength{\itemindent}{0em}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `outlines` package is quite simple, and simply provides a wrapper around the basic lists (by default, `itemize`). So you can use the `enumitem` package to adjust the list parameters for the `itemize` lists as you see fit, but still use `outlines` for your input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{itemindent=\parindent,labelsep=1em}
  \usepackage{outlines}
   \begin{document}
    \section{title}
     \begin{outline}
          \1 Online frei verfügbar für alle
          \1 Einfach in der Bedienung
          \2 Auf mobilen Geräten automatisch laufen. - ohne Zwischenschritte.
          \2 Den Benutzer unterstützen in der Suche der beschriebenen Objekten.
          \1 Offlinefähig - Keine Datenabhängigkeit während der Tour.
     \end{outline}
  \end{document}
```

[image: output of code]